# Solving $|2x+8|^2 -|9x+36|-9=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

it looks easy but I messed up something with steps.

> $$|2x+8|^2 -|9x+36|-9=0$$

This is what I got

$$|2(x+4)|^2 - | 9(x+4)| - 9 = 0$$

Then I used $u = (x+4)$ and here where it got complicated.

Comment: Hint: $|u| =-u$ if $u<0$ and $|u|=u$ if $u\geq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than letting $u = x+4$, you could instead write
$$|2(x+4)|^2 - |9(x+4)| - 9 = 2^2|x+4|^2 - 9|x+4| - 9 = 4u^2 - 9u - 9,$$ where $u = |x+4|$.  This quadratic factors:

$$4u^2 - 9u - 9 = (u-3)(4u + 3).$$  Alternatively, we can complete the square, or we can simply apply the quadratic formula.  In any case, this yields
$$u \in \left\{3, -\frac{3}{4}\right\}$$ but only one of these is a solution, since $u = |x+4|$ implies $u \ge 0$.  This gives $$|x+4| = 3$$ which in turn implies $x \in \{-1, -7\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint I gave you:
$$4u^2-9u+9=0\,\,\, u\geq 0\,\,\implies u=\frac{9\pm\sqrt{9^2+16\cdot 9}}{8}\implies u=3 \lor u=-\frac{3}{4}$$

Also:
$$4u^2+9u+9=0\,\,\ u\leq 0\implies ,\implies u=\frac{-9\pm\sqrt{9^2+16\cdot 9}}{8}\implies u=\frac{3}{4}\lor u=-3$$

So, the solutions are: $x=-1\lor x=-7$.

Comment: @Riddle2795: sorry for that error. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method when working with equations involving absolute values.

It consists in replacing $|x|$ by $\, \sigma x\, $ where $\sigma=\pm 1$, however if it simplifies the calculation by avoiding the sign discussions (i.e. $x$ belongs to which or which interval), it also often produces spurious solutions, so we need to plug the obtained values into the initial equation and see if they actually work.

$\begin{align}|2x+8|^2-|9x+36|-9
&=(2x+8)^2-\sigma(9x+36)-9\\
&=4x^2+(32-9\sigma)x+(55-36\sigma)\\
\end{align}$

$\Delta=144+81\overbrace{\sigma^2}^{=1}=225=15^2$

The roots of the quadratic are $x=\dfrac{-32+9\sigma\pm 15}{8}=-7,\ -\frac{19}4,\ -\frac{13}4,\ -1$

And two of them $-1,-7$ are solutions, the other two have to be discarded.

Of course here, there was a simplification since $|x+4|$ could be factored out, but you can learn this method for when you'll have to face equations with no apparent simplification.